# Can't configure AWS account to connect so S3

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following code that won't compile and all examples I've seen would indicate it's correct:

```
// AWSServiceConfiguration.swift
import Foundation
import AWSCore

class AWSServiceConfiguration {

    static let shared = AWSServiceConfiguration()

    private init() {
        let accessKey = "YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY"
        let secretKey = "YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY"
        let region = AWSRegionType.USWest2.rawValue
        
        let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
        let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: region, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration
    }
}
```

I get the error for this line of code:

```
let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: region, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
```

Error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Note that I run `init() { _ = AWSServiceConfiguration.shared }` under @main. I am using the aws-sdk-ios-spm package on Xcode.

Been trying to troubleshoot this for hours to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you defined your own `AWSServiceConfiguration` class with the same name as the one in the aws sdk?  That doesn't seem like a good idea but if you really want it like that you can resolve the ambiguity by using the module name when creating the aws one: `let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSCore.AWSServiceConfiguration(region: region, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)`

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" indicates that the AWSServiceConfiguration initializer is expecting no arguments, but you are passing region and credentialsProvider as arguments. This suggests that the AWSServiceConfiguration class has been updated and the initializer signature has changed.

To fix this, you can try changing the AWSServiceConfiguration initializer call to use the new signature, like this:

```
let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: region, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)!
```

Note the use of the ! at the end of the line to force-unwrap the optional value returned by the initializer. This assumes that the initializer will always succeed, so use this with caution and make sure to handle any errors that may arise.

If this doesn't work, you may need to check the documentation or release notes for the version of the aws-sdk-ios-spm package you are using to see if there were any changes to the AWSServiceConfiguration class that might affect your code.

```
import Foundation
import AWSCore

class AWSServiceConfiguration {

    static let shared = AWSServiceConfiguration()

    private init() {
        let accessKey = "YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY"
        let secretKey = "YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY"
        let region = AWSRegionType.USWest2
        
        let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
        let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: region, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
        
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah now it's saying that

AWSServiceConfiguration.swift:15:66 Argument passed to call that takes no arguments (and suggests I remove all arguments)

AWSServiceConfiguration.swift:15:124 Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'AWSServiceConfiguration' (and suggests I remove the !)

Thank you for your help. I will review the documentation and see if I can find any changes in the implementation. I am a bit intimidated by the task but can't hurt to try :P

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?